# How to get more options in the Viewport shading?

Tags: texturing, shaders

in another question thread i made. Another community member showed me his viewport shading window. in his window he had alot more options than mine.

His screen:
[image]

My screen:
[image]

How would i be able to get those options too?
The blender version that i am using is 2.9 by the way.

Comment: You need to be in Solid Preview mode to get the options to choose a matcap - . (Second circle from the left) . These options will not appear in Wireframe, Material Preview (LookDev), or Rendered Preview modes.

Comment: You are showing 2 different things: Matcaps for Solid preview in the first case, which are sort of material + light simulations, and HDRI, which are environments, for Material preview in the second case. So you must switch to Solid preview to see the kind of matcaps you show. By default you'll have less matcaps but you can download and install some, click on the little gear icon on the right of the matcaps list.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are viewing in solid mode and go back into the menu to choose the matcap you'd like to you. You should be able to change it and see your changes clearly from there.